# Error en iOS cuando envio un parametro a la funcion, me sale como ArgumentInvalid

Tags: ios, objective-c

La funcion debe recibir un parametro string, y luego ese string que recibe enviarlo como nombre de un label que esta en pantalla

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // DECLARANDO EL LABEL
    label_principal = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 600, 400, 100)];
    [label_principal setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [label_principal setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
    [label_principal setTextColor: [UIColor blackColor]];
    [label_principal setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    // INVOCANDO LOS ELEMENTOS EN PANTALLA
    [self.view addSubview:label_principal];

    _captureSession = nil;
    [self startReading];
}

// FUNCION QUE RECIBE UN PARAMETRO
- (void)CapturarParametro:(NSString *)recibido{
    //CAPTURADORA
    [label_principal setText:recibido];
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está tratando de llamar al método de instancia CapturarParametro: de la clase BarcodeReader. ¿Donde está definido ese método? ¿Quién lo llama?

Comment: Agrega la llamada a CapturarParametro ahi es donde debe encontrarse el error, Ademas dice unrecognize selector eso significa que estas usando "CapturarParametro" como un selector? muestranos donde lo pasas como selector